# Cannot select in SQLite database using Pentaho Data Integration : java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet closed

Tags: sqlite, pentaho, kettle

I'm trying to use a SQLite database to make a Table Input step in Pentaho Data Integration. Connection seems fine...

```
Connection to database [Volp_2] is OK.
Hostname       : C:\Users\Aluno\Apps\VOLP\BD\volp.db
Port           : -1
Database name  : *****
```

... but previewing first 1000 rows through Table Input step

```
2014/05/26 11:18:14 - Table input.0 - ERROR (version 5.0.1-stable, build 1 from 2013-11-15_16-08-58 by buildguy) : Erro inesperado
2014/05/26 11:18:14 - Table input.0 - ERROR (version 5.0.1-stable, build 1 from 2013-11-15_16-08-58 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
2014/05/26 11:18:14 - Table input.0 - An error occurred executing SQL: 
2014/05/26 11:18:14 - Table input.0 - select nome from palavras
2014/05/26 11:18:14 - Table input.0 - [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: palavras)
2014/05/26 11:18:14 - Table input.0 - 
2014/05/26 11:18:14 - Table input.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.openQuery(Database.java:1641)
2014/05/26 11:18:14 - Table input.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableinput.TableInput.doQuery(TableInput.java:233)
2014/05/26 11:18:14 - Table input.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableinput.TableInput.processRow(TableInput.java:143)
2014/05/26 11:18:14 - Table input.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:60)
2014/05/26 11:18:14 - Table input.0 -   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
2014/05/26 11:18:14 - Table input.0 - Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: palavras)
2014/05/26 11:18:14 - Table input.0 -   at org.sqlite.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:383)
2014/05/26 11:18:14 - Table input.0 -   at org.sqlite.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:387)
2014/05/26 11:18:14 - Table input.0 -   at org.sqlite.DB.throwex(DB.java:374)
2014/05/26 11:18:14 - Table input.0 -   at org.sqlite.NativeDB.prepare(Native Method)
2014/05/26 11:18:14 - Table input.0 -   at org.sqlite.DB.prepare(DB.java:123)
2014/05/26 11:18:14 - Table input.0 -   at org.sqlite.Stmt.executeQuery(Stmt.java:121)
2014/05/26 11:18:14 - Table input.0 -   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.openQuery(Database.java:1630)
2014/05/26 11:18:14 - Table input.0 -   ... 4 more
2014/05/26 11:18:14 - C:\Users\Aluno\Apps\App.ktr : App - ERROR (version 5.0.1-stable, build 1 from 2013-11-15_16-08-58 by buildguy) : Something went wrong while trying to stop the transformation: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
2014/05/26 11:18:14 - C:\Users\Aluno\Apps\App.ktr : App - Error cancelling statement
2014/05/26 11:18:14 - C:\Users\Aluno\Apps\App.ktr : App - ResultSet closed
2014/05/26 11:18:14 - C:\Users\Aluno\Apps\App.ktr : App - ERROR (version 5.0.1-stable, build 1 from 2013-11-15_16-08-58 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
2014/05/26 11:18:14 - C:\Users\Aluno\Apps\App.ktr : App - Error cancelling statement
2014/05/26 11:18:14 - C:\Users\Aluno\Apps\App.ktr : App - ResultSet closed
2014/05/26 11:18:14 - C:\Users\Aluno\Apps\App.ktr : App - 
2014/05/26 11:18:14 - C:\Users\Aluno\Apps\App.ktr : App -   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.cancelStatement(Database.java:664)
2014/05/26 11:18:14 - C:\Users\Aluno\Apps\App.ktr : App -   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.cancelQuery(Database.java:646)
2014/05/26 11:18:14 - C:\Users\Aluno\Apps\App.ktr : App -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableinput.TableInput.stopRunning(TableInput.java:303)
2014/05/26 11:18:14 - C:\Users\Aluno\Apps\App.ktr : App -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.Trans.stopAll(Trans.java:1729)
2014/05/26 11:18:14 - C:\Users\Aluno\Apps\App.ktr : App -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.BaseStep.stopAll(BaseStep.java:2605)
2014/05/26 11:18:14 - C:\Users\Aluno\Apps\App.ktr : App -   at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:95)
2014/05/26 11:18:14 - C:\Users\Aluno\Apps\App.ktr : App -   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
2014/05/26 11:18:14 - C:\Users\Aluno\Apps\App.ktr : App - Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet closed
2014/05/26 11:18:14 - C:\Users\Aluno\Apps\App.ktr : App -   at org.sqlite.RS.checkOpen(RS.java:63)
2014/05/26 11:18:14 - C:\Users\Aluno\Apps\App.ktr : App -   at org.sqlite.Stmt.cancel(Stmt.java:254)
2014/05/26 11:18:14 - C:\Users\Aluno\Apps\App.ktr : App -   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.cancelStatement(Database.java:659)
```

What am I doing wrong? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

This is already covered at 
https://gobansaor.wordpress.com/2006/12/18/sqlite-jdbc-and-kettle-pentaho-data-integration-etl/

Here are the steps in case that article is removed:

```
1. Within SPOON, make a new connection using for example a Table Input step.
2. In the General tab, pick “Generic database” from the list of connection types.
3. Pick “Native(JDBC)” from the Method of Access list.
No further information required on this tab, go to the Generic tab.
4. In the URL field, enter “jdbc:sqlite:c:\mydata\mydatabase.db” where c:\mydata\mydatabase.db is the SQLite database you wish to connect to.
5. In the Driver class field, enter “org.sqlite.JDBC”.
```

Previously the jar file including the JDBC class must be saved into the data-integration\lib folder.

Answer (score 1):

Well this error looks like the cause:

```
select nome from palavras
```

Since it is complaining that the table does not exist...

Are you sure the table is spelled right or does it have a database name associated?  If you connect directly with sqlite3 and run the query, does this query work?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, for me the correct answer is from [Mario.Cadiz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54221998/4021625) (sorry I don't have reputation for comments)

I've defined two connections, first with sqlite type and second for generic database.

**sqlite type**

- Host Name: jdbc:sqlite:/home/jose/demo.db
- Database Name: demo
- port: <empty>
- Username: <empty>
- Password: <empty>

I've tested the connection correctly, but Explore function don't show any table

**Generic database type**

- Dialect: Generic database
- Custom connection URL: jdbc:sqlite:/home/jose/demo.db
- Custom driver class name: org.sqlite.JDBC
- Username: <empty>
- Password: <empty>

Test and Explore functions are right, I can explore all tables in database.

**PDI version 9.2.0.0-290 (Ubuntu 20.04)**
**The sqlite driver comes already installed with this version of pdi (lib directory)**